# jekyll server not running

Tags: git, jekyll

I am trying to run jekyll in my local and it doesn't seem to be running. I have the proper directory structure as it requires.

I went to my directory path where my `_config.yml` resides. And then i ran the command `jekyll serve -w` when i run the above command i get something like this

```
Configuration file: /home/abc/git/xyz/_config.yml
Source: /home/abc/git/xyz
Destination: /home/abc/git/xyz/_site
Generating... error: no time information in "{}". Use --trace to view backtrace
```

and then it stops execution.

I have tried the following ways too.

ran using `jekyll --source /home/abc/git/xyz --destination /home/abc/git/xyz/_site`

Also tried adding following lines

```
host : 0.0.0.0
port : 4000
url: http://localhost:4000
baseurl : /
```

But nothing seems to work. I use linux machine FYI

Let me know, if any information needed.

Any help appreciated !!!

Comment: What is the jekyll and ruby version you are using ?

Comment: See this as well : https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/649

Comment: jekyll : 1.4.3, ruby : 1.9.3

Comment: @MadhurAhuja i checked the link and the version which i use seems to be fine. I am unsure on that prose thing which is been mentioned in the last.

Comment: It seems there is problem with YAML of one your posts. Can you post the sample YAML of your post. Make sure your date/time is in correct format if specified for any.

Comment: I am new to this jekyll. I just went to my _posts dir. I find many files here with different dates Ex : 2013-11-28-history.markdown. etc etc. Is this what needed ??

Comment: Yes, can you post the contents of one of this files .. especially the top header

Comment: ---
layout: post
title:  "Welcome to Jekyll!"
date:   2013-11-27 22:50:01
categories: jekyll update
---

Comment: I have cloned this code from the working environment and nothing i have touched it. For start i am trying to install in my local where i am facing the problem.

Comment: @MadhurAhuja yes, you were right. In one of the file there was a missing date on the header. There is no error now. Site is loading now. But with some errors.

Comment: Any idea on this please ...............   error sass/main.scss (Line 2: File to import not found or unreadable: ../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.
Load paths:
  /home/abc/git/xyz (DEPRECATED)
  /home/abc/git/xyz/sass)

Comment: It seems you are missing some ruby gems. I think this one https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

Comment: I installed it...it says gem installed. I restarted jekyll but still same error.